# Upload Multiple Ftp Files once

Tags: c#, ftp

Im working at C#, I have 4 files, How to upload them all at once?
I have this, But this only works at 1 file.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("(secret)/keystock1.txt");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("secret", "secret");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("keystock1.txt");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("STOCK Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

Comment: Use Multithreading, backgroudworker or AsynAwait.

Comment: you could put your code in a foreach loop , then loop threw all the files and execute your code on them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Async` tasks. A class like following would achieve this:

```
public class FileUploadsManager
{
    //pass in the list of file paths which u want to upload.
    public static async void UploadFilesAsync(string[] filePaths)
    {
        List<Task> fileUploadingTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
        {
            fileUploadingTasks.Add(UploadFileAsync(filePath));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(fileUploadingTasks);
    }

    public static Task UploadFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //this is your code with a few changes

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                    string.Format("(secret)/{0}", Path.GetFileName(filePath))
                );

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("secret", "secret");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(await sourceStream.ReadToEndAsync());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("STOCK Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        });
    }
}
```

You can call this as follows:

```
string[] paths = new string[] { "C:\file1.txt", "C:\file2.txt", "C:\file2.txt" };

FileUploadsManager.UploadFilesAsync(paths);
```